# RESTful webservices DELETE returns 400 Bad Request but GET works

Tags: rest, web-services, jax-rs, http-delete

I am trying to send a Delete request but it doesn't work. Oddly enough it works if I just change @DELETE to @GET.

```
@Stateless
@Path("orders")

public class OrderRestful {
    @Inject 
    BestellungRepository bestellrepo;

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response deleteBestellung(@PathParam("id") long id){

        Bestellung b = bestellrepo.getBestellungById(id);

        if(b == null){
            return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }

        bestellrepo.deleteBestellung(b);

        return Response.noContent().build();
    }


}
```

Since it works fine with @GET so I know the code per se is not the problem. I guess there is a syntax problem somewhere I am missing but I don't know where. I am using glassfish 5 and it is a jersey project.

Edit: I tried to make it a void method. Didn't work. I tried not using Path. It didn't work.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a complete runnable test [like this one](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/13fe79f0e572bbbec6ca486e4501fe5a), using [Jersey Test Framework](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)? There is really nothing in your post that leads me to believe could be the cause. Having a runnable example would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the code itself wasn't wrong at all. The tool I tested it with was. I tested it with Advanced Rest Client for Chrome and it throws Bad Request. When I test it with the RestClient for Firefox it works without a problem. So the Problem is solved now :)

Comment: what was the problem with ARC?